# Finding country code before payment in Stripe

Tags: javascript, vue.js, sass, stripe-payments

Is there a way find the country code (using vuejs/elements) *before* handling stripe payment? I'd like to have the country drive specific events such as calculating the fees etc before payment.

Answer (score 1):

You can [create a PaymentMethod](https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_methods) using Stripe Elements, check the [country](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object#payment_method_object-card-country) and then proceed with the payment using the saved PaymentMethod:

```
stripe
  .confirmCardPayment('{PAYMENT_INTENT_CLIENT_SECRET}', {
    payment_method: "pm_abc123", // id of the saved payment method
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    // Handle result.error or result.paymentIntent
  });
```